# Проверка соответствия кода реакт-приложения стандартам WCAG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Какие есть решения для проверки кода реакт-приложения на соответствие WCAG-стандартам?

Как понимаю, проблема в том, что WCAG рассматривает уже построенный DOM на наличие специфических тегов, атрибутов и подобных вещей. А в случае c реактом, наш код разнесен по компонентам.

Воспользовался, рекомендацией из доков реакта - [использование плагина ally](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/accessibility.html#development-assistance), однако, при запуске линтера он не указывает только на ошибки js, связанные с accessibility.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, рецептами решения этой проблемы.

Comment: Если eslint не показывает ошибки в коде jsx, вероятно плагин или сам eslint настроен некорректно. Пробовали использовать готовые конфиги  вроде `eslint-config-airbnb`?

Comment: @IgorGolovin ошибки не accessibility находит

Comment: А вам нужны только ошибки accessibility, а остальные не выводить?

Comment: @IgorGolovin нужны все. сейчас получаю все, кроме ассесабилити

Comment: На конфиге `eslint-config-airbnb` ошибки от плагина a11y прекрастно выводятся. https://monosnap.com/file/6J63aAO2U1k6LSArkdOF2DcYpWIc88 У вас какие настройки eslint используются?

Comment: @IgorGolovin да, только убедился, что выводятся, у меня оказывается проект уже соответсвует минимальному WCAG) такой вопрос, можно указать сразу AA или AAA соответствие? или придется вручную правила прописывать? потому что plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended покрывает не все ошибки, приходится в пару подключать react-axe

Comment: Попробуйте использовать конфиг `plugin:jsx-a11y/strict` вместо `plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended` или настройте под себя. Там не так много правил.

Comment: @IgorGolovin да, строгий режим тоже не зашел, что-то пропускает

Comment: @IgorGolovin оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ